# Managed anonymous shared memory with boost::interprocess

Tags: c++, mmap, boost-interprocess

I am trying to share memory between processes after a `fork()`, `boost::interprocess` offers a way to do exactly this by using their `anonymous_shared_memory`as shown [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.anonymous_shared_memory). However the library also provides `managed_shared_memory` objects which have very useful allocators and deallocators. But it doesn't seem possible to create a `managed_shared_memory` object from the `mapped_region` returned by the `anonymous_shared_memory` call. Am I missing something ?